# C++ Programs can't run from Notepad++

Tags: c++, mingw, notepad++

I've tried to compile the c++ programs from the Notepad++ editor.
I am using mingw64 g++ compiler here.
Added the execution script using NppExec plugin in notepad++, the script I have used is given below,

```
npp_save
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

Saved this script as a macro and executed to run a cpp program, but getting the System error The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing from your computer.

The same mingw64 compiler am using in Code::Blocks and its working fine.
How we can solve this issue ?

Comment: Make sure that `libwinpthread-1.dll` is accessible through your `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd /k gcc -o "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" && CLS && "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe" & PAUSE & EXIT
```

Press ctrl+F5 and input this command, then click 'run'. You can also save it as a shortcut.